# Is (*x).y the same as x->y?

Tags: c, struct, dereference

Is operator `->` allowed to use in C instead of `.`? Does its availability depend on compiler we are using? Is `->` operator available in the last C standard or does it come from the C++ standard? How those two differ?

Comment: Yes. `x->y` is shorthand for `(*x).y`. It has been available from the beginning of C. Actually nobody would write `(*x).y`.

Comment: Unless `->` is overridden, if I understand correct.

Comment: @MichaelWalz It is not a shorthand. It is simply different way of doing the same thing

Comment: @bereal You cannot "override" built-in operators in C.

Comment: @unwind the question is tagged `c++`... Ok, no longer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In C, `c->m` is equivalent to `(*c).m`. The parentheses are necessary since `.` has a higher precedence than `*`. Any respectable compiler will generate the same code.

In C++, unless `->` or `*` is [overloaded](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading), the equivalence is as above.

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to overload the `->` and `.`operators in C++?

Comment: @Lundin `.`, not. `->`, definitely yes.

Comment: @Lundin `->` is overloadable and Bjarne wants to make `.` overloadable as well for the C++17 in order to have smart references akin to smart pointers http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4477.pdf.

Comment: @Lundin: we'll split 50/50. You can't override `.`.

Comment: Unless `->` *or `*`* is overriden.

Comment: That's certainly true. You can override `*` as a dereference and as multiplication. See boost spirit.

Comment: @Ludin sure -> can. smart pointers do it all the time. `.` cannot, along with `? :`, `.*`, `::`, `sizeof` and `typeid`.

Comment: Well, wow. Overloading `->` or `.` seems severely brain-damaged to me... Allowing you to overload one of them but not the other even more so. Why would anyone want to do that?! Allowing it will mean it will get abused.

Comment: C++ gives you the opportunity to shoot yourself in the foot. That's up to you. Overloading `->` *can* be useful when building managed pointer classes. My strongest dislike of Java is the fact that it doesn't allow operator overloading. I find working with some classes, e.g. `BigInteger` frustrating.

Comment: @Lundin Overloading `->` is indeed *extremely* useful when creating a pointer-like class (think `std::unique_ptr`). On the other hand, you need *some* form of being guaranteed access to a member `y` or object `x` when you have `x`, so one operator needs to remain unoverloadable. And that's `.`.

Comment: I really don't see how it would be "extremely useful" for anyone to open up the language for bugs like: `std::committee* member1, member2; member1->brainstorm(); member2->brainstorm();`

Comment: @Bathsheba No, shoot yourself in the foot is C. C++ is blow your leg off :) Java is boring because there's no flashy explosions.

Answer (score 5):

There are 3 operators here, `*`, `.` and `->`. This is important, because `.` and `->` both have precedence 1, but `*` has [precedence 2](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). Therefore `*foo.bar` is not the same as `foo->bar` and parenthesis are required, like in `(*foo).bar`.

All are original C operators and have been around forever.

Answer (score 5):

In C, `a->b` and `(*a).b` are 100% equivalent, and the very reason for introduction of `->` into C was precedence—so that you don't have to type the parentheses in `(*a)`.

In C++, `operator *` and `operator ->` can be overridden independently, so you can no longer say that `a->b` and `(*a).b` are equivalent in all cases. They are, however, 100% equivalent when `a` is of a built-in pointer type.

Comment: You are correct that they can be theoretically different.  In practise, the only reason I can think of to make them different is as an entry in the International Obfuscate C++ Competition (A thing which has never happened - probably because there is no *challenge* to it.)

Comment: @MartinBonner Or they can be different *by accident.* When looking for an elusive bug, it's good to know what can be absolutely taken for granted. Everything else is potentially suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

Operator `->` is standard in C. Both `.` and `->` allow to access a `struct` field. You should use `.` on a `struct` variable and `->` on a `struct pointer` variable.

```
struct foo {
    int x;
    int y;
}

struct foo f1;
f1.x = 1;
f1.y = 3;
struct foo *f2 = &f1;
printf("%d\n", f1.x);     // 1
printf("%d\n", f2->x);    // 1
```

The `*` operator is called `dereference operator` and returns the value at the pointer address. So `(*f2).x` is equivalent to `f2->x`.

Answer (score 0):

In general case, yes - compiler should produce the same code for both. But these operators can be overloaded and thus have different functions.